# How to post one html form data into two models in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I having a html form consisting of some fields with details and I want to post some details of the form to one model and some details to another model how this can be done?
my models.py

```
class room(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='0000000')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

# This is the model for goals   
class goal(models.Model):
    id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    goal = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='0000000')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.goal

# This is the model for designs
class design(models.Model):
    id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='0000000')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

# This is the model for furniture
class furniture(models.Model):
    id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    phrase=models.CharField(max_length=60,default='111111')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.phrase

# This is the users model
class user(models.Model):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=50,default='0000000')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class UserRequirement(models.Model):
    id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(user,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rooms = models.ForeignKey(room,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    goals = models.ManyToManyField(goal)
    styles = models.ManyToManyField(design)
    furn = models.ForeignKey(furniture,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

My views.py for posting:

```
def user_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            username=request.POST["username"]
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            rooms = request.POST['room']
            g=goals=request.POST['goal']
            g = g.split(',')
            s=styles=request.POST['style']
            s=s.split(',')
            furn=request.POST['furn']
            u = user(username=username,password=password,email=email)
            u.rooms=room.objects.get(pk=rooms)
            goals = goal.objects.filter(pk__in=g)
            styles = design.objects.filter(pk__in=s)
            u.furn = furniture.objects.get(pk=furn)
            u.save()
            u.goals.add(*goals)
            u.styles.add(*styles)
            messages.success(request,'Your project design has been registered')
            return render(request,'register.html')
        else:
            messages.warning(request,'Cant be registered this email already exists')
            return render(request,'register.html')
```

My form.html is

```
<form action="{% url 'modsy:user_register' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="username">Username</label>
              <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" required>
              <div id="uname_error"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="hidden" name="room" id="name" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" >
              <input type="hidden" name="goal" id="goal" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="hidden" name="style" id="style" value=" ">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" >
              <input type="hidden" name="furn" id="furn" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" required><br>
              <div id="name_error" style="color:red;"></div></div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password2">Password</label>
              <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
              <div id="pwd_error" style="color:red;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="button"><input type="submit" value="Save the Project" style="background-color:#000080;" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" onclick="return validation(form)">
          </form>
```

Now here I want to post the username email and password to the user model and the user room goal furniture style should be stored in the user_requirement model how it can be done?

My forms.py

```
from django import forms
from . models import user
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from . models import UserRequirement
from . models import room
from . models import goal
from . models import design
from . models import furniture




class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = user
        fields = ('email',)

    def clean_email(self):
        # Get the email
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        # Check to see if any users already exist with this email as a username.
        try:
            match = User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            # Unable to find a user, this is fine
            return email
            raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already in use.')

class UserRequirementForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserRequirement
        fields=(user,rooms,goals,styles,furn)
```

Comment: use `ForeignKey`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Comment: @Yeganeh I had used but the data should be stored in other model now how can you say

Comment: @Yeganeh on request.post the details are storing in same model but I want them in two models

Comment: edit your post with `ForeignKey ` usage

Comment: @Yegneh I didnt understand where I should edit

Comment: You're saving user passwords in the clear in your database. I hope this is just a hobby project not for real use, because this is not how you should create users. Django has built-in auth functionality that you should use if you want to register users.

Comment: @dirkgroten its just a hobby not for real use can you say how can I achieve my requirement

Comment: The answer below is correct. I've edited it to make it a little more useful.

Comment: @ dirkgroten then in forms.py for userRequirementForm what I should write I am not getting

Comment: Then where should I take my fields @dirkgoten

Comment: It should be a `ModelForm` for the model `UserRequirement`.

Comment: @ dirkgroten I added my forms.py code once check I am not getting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205510/discussion-between-g-lakshmi-and-dirkgroten).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**: Create a form with all the fields you need and override the save method to store the data where you need them. You can use your `User` model as the base model and add any extra fields you need for other models.

**Option 2**: Use two different forms and process them separately.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
    user_requirement_form = UserRequirementForm(data=request.POST)
    if user_form.is_valid() and user_requirement_form.is_valid():
        user = user_form.save()
        user_requirement = user_requirement_form.save(commit=False)
        # Set user
        user_requirement.user = user
        user_requirement.save()
        user_requirement_form.save_m2m()
        redirect(...)
    else:
       # Handle errors
       messages.warning(request, 'Please correct the errors below')
else:  
    # GET
    user_form = UserForm()
    user_requirement_form = UserRequirementForm()
return render(request,'register.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'requirements_form': user_requirement_form})
```

Then make sure you actually show the errors in your template, using `{{ user_form.errors }}` or `{{ user_form.email.errors }}` depending whether you show all the errors at once or per field.

Comment: @ Navid In the same html form I am getting all the details now I need them to be seperately stored in the two models how?

Comment: can I write the same view two times to store the details in the two models

Comment: @G.Lakshmi You need to add all the fields you need in your HTML all as a single form. Then in your view, pass the post data to all the forms you created and process them separately like the example code. `UserForm` will use the fields that it needs and store them as `User` and `UserRequirementForm` will store the fields it needs as `UserRequirement`.

Comment: @ Navid The User is taken as the foreignkey in UserRequirement when storing (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")
getting error like this what to do please say this

Comment: @G.Lakshmi You should set the user before saving to the database. Check the example code. notice `user_requirement_form.save(commit=False)` and `user_requirement.user = user`

Comment: Ok I should do this only with forms not the models right @Navid

Comment: can I write this statement in my views user_requirement.user = user before saving

Comment: Yes but I dont have forms.py for my code now what should I include in forms.py as you included the forms in the view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205507/discussion-between-g-lakshmi-and-navid-zarepak).

Comment: just a normal form: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: Yes @Navid I wrote the forms same as you sent the link

Answer (score 1):

I think the following approach would help.

1. Forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = user
        fields = ['email',]


class UserRequirementForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserRequirement
        fields=['rooms','goals','styles','furn']
```

Then 2. Views.py

```
from .forms import UserForm, UserRequirementForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render

def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        user_requirement_form = UserRequirementForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and user_requirement_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user_requirement = user_requirement_form.save(commit=False)

            user_requirement.user = request.user # <- Setting the user to currently logged in user
            user_requirement.save()
            redirect('name_of_url_to_redirect_to')

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        user_requirement_form = UserRequirementForm()

    context = {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'user_requirement_form' : user_requirement_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'path_to_template.html', context)
```

Then finally in the template (.html file):

```
<form method="POST">
    {{user_form.as_p}}
    {{user_requirement_form.as_p}}

    <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
</form>
```

That should render your form and save data correctly on submit

**PS: Avoid adding id field on your models as Django already gives you an id field by default.**

Comment: @ Abedy that means there should not be anything in the form except this in the html form

Comment: @G.Lakshmi Yes. Check out - Django templating

Comment: But I am getting the data from javascript into form fields

Comment: Django will automatically render the fields for you based on the forms you specified in the views. So per say no Javascript is required. Once the submit button is clicked, the url rendering that form is called, and in turn the method `register_user` is called. Remember Django is an MVC framework.

Note we are defining a dictionary `context` in the views. That is what renders your form to the specified template

Comment: No thats not the issue for some fields I am getting the data from javascript function that I wrote

Comment: Then could you update your question with the Javascript function?

Comment: There are four fields that I am getting the data from js

Comment: <body onload = "isValue();sample();initGoals();issample();initStyles();assample();">
  <div class="container20">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205515/discussion-between-abedy-and-g-lakshmi).